# Is there a performance difference between an int and a struct containing only an int?

Tags: c, performance, struct, int

In C, a typedef doesn't grant you any additional type safety. You can use the the new type any place you can use the old type. Sometimes that's what I want, and sometimes it is not. Sometimes I want the compiler to warn me if I misuse my new type.

To make that happen, I sometimes do something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
} NewType;

NewType doSomethingNT(NewType a, NewType b) {
    return a.value + b.value;
}
```

Compared to:

```
int doSomethingI(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

(That plus is just an example. Let's assume that either there's a function call overhead in both cases, or else I ask the function to be inlined in both cases. But let's not compare doSomethingNT to the bare + operator, obviously the latter is faster because it doesn't have the function call overhead)

I guess I'm asking, is there any overhead in "boxing" a primitive type a one element struct, but using that struct as a value type. (I.e. I'm not calling malloc and using pointers to it like how boxing works in Java.)

Comment: The only overhead is compilation time

Comment: Veeeerrrry similar to [c-class-wrapper-around-fundamental-types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793298/c-class-wrapper-around-fundamental-types), but that's about C++...

Comment: This is interesting but probably the best answer is to measure some actual programs, version 1 using plain types, version 2 using your "box types". Probably the optimizer can make version 2 no slower than version 1

Comment: Measuring such a small change can be difficult since if there is overhead, it's likely to be quite minimal. The best way to answer this question, I think, is to compile each version to assembly and see what the difference is (if any).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this with the clang (specifically `Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)`) at -O2.

The source:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct da_int {
    short i;
};

struct da_int add(struct da_int x, struct da_int y) {
    struct da_int rv = {x.i + y.i};
    return rv;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct da_int x = {5}, y = {3};
    printf("%d\n", add(x, y).i);
}
```

The compiler foiled my plan slightly—the generated main never calls add, instead computing the result at compile-time:

```
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq    %rbp
Ltmp7:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp8:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp9:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $8, %esi
    xorb    %al, %al
    callq    _printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

It did generate an add function though! It takes its arguments in registers and returns a result in a register. The wrapper struct disappears completely in the compiler output, at least for this trivial case:

```
_add:                                   ## @add
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq    %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    addl    %esi, %edi
    movw    %di, %ax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Given that, I wouldn't worry too much about extra overhead from doing this.