# Changing Assigned Value for STL Map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

As I create a `std::map`, all the indexes are initially pointing nowhere. As soon as I call them, they allocated and assigned the value 0.

For example:

```
map <int, int> x;
cout << x.[31233];
```

The output is `0`.

However, I need that all the standard assigned value to be `(-1)` instead of `0`.

How can I change this?

Comment: You can't not by using standard types like `int` for the data anyway. You *could* possibly create a class that can be implicitly converted to an `int` and whose constructor sets the value to `-1` on construction.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Thank you" and "Hello" are usually omitted here, it's all about the raw question.

Comment: `std::map<>::operator[]` auto-inserts and value-initializes the value for a key if it wasn't present in the map. (and `int()` is zero). If you want something different, you likely need to `find(key)` the key, and if the resulting iterator is `x.end()`, `insert` it with (-1) for the value.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg well, in theory you could write a custom allocator which initializes to `-1`.. But why would you want to do that ;)

Comment: @lethal-guitar because you *can* ? =P

Answer (score 2):

After this definition

```
map <int, int> x;
```

the map has no elements. To add an element with key `31233` and value `-1` you can write

```
x[31233] = -1;
```

You can not do such a way that the default value would be -1 because according to the C++ Standard relative to the subscript operator

> If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts value_type(x, T()) into the map

For type `int` `int()` zero initializes the corresponding object.

Otherwise you should use some `insert` method where you will explicitly specify an initial value.

Answer (score 1):

Given a `std::map<key_type, value_type>`, a lookup for an arbitrary key through `operator [](cont key_type&)` will auto-insert `value_type()` for said-key if it wasn't present. In your case, `value_type` is `int`, and `int()` is zero-initialized, therefore zero is the result.

if you want to use a different default construct, you have options, the most extreme of which would be writing a custom allocator specialized for `int` and a `construct` member to us -1 for `int` value types (yuck). I think you may find it easier to simply:

```
std::map <int, int> x;

// load map with values...

int res = -1;
auto it = x.find(31233);
if (it != x.end())
    res = x.second;

// use res here.
```

Comment: The allocator thing won't work: see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333728/stdmap-default-value#comment2316284_2333786).

Comment: @interjay I swear I've done it, but I probably broke the rules in doing so. One *could* do something utterly dreadful and just spin an `Integer` class with a boatload of overloads and a default construct of (-1) rather than 0, then map int-to-Integer. talk about yuck.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply stop using the `operator[]` and instead use `insert()` when you intend to insert a new value.  If you want to have a "default" value for things that have never been inserted, it may be better to write your own container which uses a map internally and exposes something like a get() method which returns the stored value from the map or -1 if not found.  That way you avoid storing lots of -1 values that aren't needed.