# Are elements added to a std::map automatically initialised?

Tags: c++, dictionary, initialization

Suppose I have a map

`std::map<int, double> foo;`

Is the behaviour on my writing `foo[2] += 3.0;` defined? That is, are any implicitly added map elements automatically initialised (hopefully to `0.0`) in my case?

If not, am I introducing a truck-load of undefined behaviour? If so, could I do something funky with an allocator to enforce initialisation to `0.0`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333728/stdmap-default-value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it will be [value-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) (as `0.0` in your case). According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to
>   key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.
>
> If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized
>   (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and
>   a reference to it is returned.

Comment: "zero-initialized otherwise". That's the crux of it. Thank you.

Comment: Has this always been true, or just in c++11? C++11 does much more to fill in defaults than previously, but I don't know if this is one of those contexts

Comment: @AaronMcDaid This is also true in C++03.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid C++11 added more syntax for value initialization but the result of value initialization didn't change.

Comment: @songyuanyao, according to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) something has changed from C++03 to C++11 in the meaning of `new T()`. *"Scalars and POD types with dynamic storage duration were considered to be not initialized (since C++11, this situation was reclassified as a form of default initialization). "*  That's why I'm curious if C++03 really is the same as C++11 as regards this question, perhaps a similar change (similar to that quote) has been introduced for `map` elements. But I suppose if there was a difference, the page you linked would say so.

Comment: (... in other words, I didn't say that the result of value initialization has changed. Just that, in some contexts (perhaps not relevant to this question), there has been a change in which initializations are used.)

Answer (score 0):

> `N3337 [map.access]/1` *Effects:* If there is no key equivalent to `x` in the map, inserts `value_type(x,T())` into the map.

`T()` is *value-initialization*, which is the case of built-in types causes zero-initialization. As such, `foo[2]` will insert a zero-initialized `double` into your map, so your code is well-defined.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they are automatically value initialized when using `operator[]` on a non existing key. Specifically in the standard it's described at §23.4.4.3/1 (when talking about `operator[]`):

> Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts `value_type(x, T())` into the map.

For most numeric types, including `double`, the expression `T()` yields a value-initialized element of that type, therefore yielding `0.0` in your case.

Comment: But a `double` doesn't really have a default constructor.

Comment: They are actually value initialized, otherwise OP's code would invoke UB.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's actually [the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1613383/493122) for `double`.

Comment: I was thinking of default initialization, since you'd originally said it is default constructed. Default initialization isn't the same thing as value initialization.

Comment: And double does not have a default constructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza That's why I said it's the same thing for `double`. The "for `double`" part is the key. Also [`double` is default constructible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c537d2c9e6373bcd). I guess you can argue that `double` does not have a constructor but it's default constructible, but that's hardly relevant here. If you want to be pedantic, so be it.